# ibmda 400.1 provider is not registered in local machhine

Tags: .net, database-connection, connection-string, ibm-midrange, oledbconnection

I am trying to connect to AS400 database from c#.net. Am getting this exception "ibmda400.1 provider is not registered in local machhine", How to resolve this ?

This is my connection string and am connecting using OLEDB

```
<add name="StudentConn" connectionString="Provider=IBMDA400.1;User ID=****;Password=*****;Data Source=****;Default Collection=*****;"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a client package installed to have the driver available.

- older [IBM i Access for Windows](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-windows)
- newer [IBM i Access Client Solution](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions) w/Windows Application Package

**updated as of 2022-01-26**
The ACS Application Packages (Windows/Linux/PASE/Mac) are downloadable from the same IBM page as the base ACS.  You don't need to get them through ESS, though you still need an IBM login ID.
[image]

Comment: I installed IBM i Access Client Solution but still the same error is repeating.Any other idea or to debug this issue.

Comment: Did you install the Windows Application Package. That's where the OS specific drivers are.  It's a separately install-able component and must be downloaded from [Entitled System Support (ESS)](https://www.ibm.com/servers/eserver/ess)  The base ACS package only includes the "run anywhere" Java components.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the Application Package and you still see this error, take a look at what's been added to the `\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework[64]\[version]\Config\machine.config` files.

I work with a sprawling legacy .NET Framework codebase with custom tweaks to the `machine.config` files and we started getting this error after a DB2 driver upgrade.

The install added a bunch of assemblyBinding entries to the runtime nodes.  Removing them resolved the issue for me.